# Как проще всего сохранить результат работы masscan для последующего его открытия в nmap

Tags: bash, sh

## сканируем все порты у всех хостов и сохраняем результат в файл

```
masscan -p0-65535  192.168.1.0/24  --rate=300 -oL mres.txt
```

## НЕ РАБОЧИЙ, пример открытия результата

```
nmap -iL res.txt -oL nres.txt
```

Пример содержимого mres(masscan):

```
#masscan
open tcp 53 192.168.1.1 1545482808
# end
```

Как проще и грамотней всего открыть файл с результатом работы masscan в nmap для последующего более детального сканирования всех найденных хостов ?

Comment: `nmap -iL res.txt`, если `res` на `mres` поменять?